# Add Next/Prev Buttons To Tabs jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to use JQ Add Next/Prev Buttons To Tabs

Video site needs

this is a Episode menu

```
<ul class="TPlayerNv">
<li class="Button STPb " data-tplayernv="Opt1"></li>
<li class="Button STPb " data-tplayernv="Opt2"></li>
<li class="Button STPb " data-tplayernv="Opt3"></li>
<li class="Button STPb " data-tplayernv="Opt4"></li>
<li class="Button STPb " data-tplayernv="Opt5"></li>
</ul>

<button class="next">next</button>
<button class="prev">prev</button>
```

I know this doesn't work

I am novice

how to modify

```
    $(".next").on("click", function() {
      var selected = $(".TPlayerNv li.STPb");
      var next = selected.next();
      if(next.length){next.addClass("STPb");selected.removeClass("STPb");}
    $("li[data-tplayernv]").click();
    });
    $(".prev").on("click", function() {
      var selected = $(".TPlayerNv li.STPb");
      var prev = selected.prev();
      if(prev.length){prev.addClass("STPb");selected.removeClass("STPb");}
    $("li[data-tplayernv]").click();
    });
```

Comment: Please check this link (https://www.bootply.com/120472)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://www.bootply.com/120472

can i use this property to .find? 
data-tplayernv="Opt1"